# Как получить пользователей для которых завершена обработка и посчитать сколько дней на это потрачено?

Tags: java, sql

У меня есть таблица с данными, User

```
id     name      status                data
===================================================
1      Alex      заявка принята        01.01.2019
2      Elena     заявка принята        01.01.2019
3      Alex      оплачено              02.01.2019
4      Elena     оплачено              02.01.2019
5      Alex      услуга предоставлена  03.01.2019
6      Irina     заявка принята        04.01.2019
```

Мне нужно получить всех пользователей, которые прошли от статуса заявка принята до статуса услуга предоставлена
в результирующей таблице мне нужно посчитать время обработки от начала обработки заявки до завершения для тех, для кого услуга предоставлена

то есть в результирующей таблице я должен получить следующее

```
id     name          time(days)
===================================================
1      Alex          3
```

Можете подкинуть идею как это делать, может быть подсказать команды sql для этого?

Comment: Кто минусует? Отличный вопрос...

Comment: @Barmaley Да тривиальный вопрос. Впрочем, я вопросы не минусую, не подумайте...

Comment: *Мне нужно получить всех пользователей, которые прошли от статуса заявка принята до статуса услуга предоставлена* Нужно отследить, что все промежуточные статусы (в показанном примере - статус "оплачено") пройдены, или они не интересуют? Возможно ли наличие в таблице двух заявок для одного и того же Name? Возможны ли в таблице ошибки (лишние или отсутствующие записи)? И укажите всё же версию сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
select A.user, (max(B.data)-min(B.data)) as days from 
(select distinct name from user) A
   inner join user B on A.user=B.user
   group by A.user
```

Надо позвать @Akina - он то точно напишет.

P.S. Под рукой нет SQL не могу проверить

Comment: *Под рукой нет SQL не могу проверить* https://dbfiddle.uk , https://www.db-fiddle.com , http://www.sqlfiddle.com и т.п.